Converting legacy TypeScript encryption to Python
I'm attempting to migrate an existing encryption and decryption method from an old TypeScript app to a new Python one. The method uses AES-256-GCM encryption, however the developer who wrote it doesn't seem to have used an authentication tag which seems to be a requirement of the encryption standard but not of the TypeScript Crypto package.
Here is the legacy code:
import type { BinaryLike } from "crypto"
import {
  type CipherGCMTypes,
  createCipheriv,
  createDecipheriv,
  randomBytes,
} from "crypto"

let secret = "abcdefghijklm"
// auto pad
if (secret.length < 32) secret += "\0".repeat(32 - secret.length)

// 256-bit/32-byte AES GCM encryption
const algorithm: CipherGCMTypes = "aes-256-gcm"

export interface EncryptionResult<TByteType> {
  iv: TByteType
  value: TByteType
}
export function encrypt(text: BinaryLike): EncryptionResult<Buffer> {
  const iv = randomBytes(16)

  const cipher = createCipheriv(algorithm, secret, iv)
  const enc = cipher.update(text)

  return {
    value: enc,
    iv,
  }
}
const b64ToBuf = (b64: string) => Buffer.from(b64, "base64url")
const bufToB64 = (buf: Buffer) => buf.toString("base64url")

export function encryptBase64Res(text: BinaryLike): EncryptionResult<string> {
  const res = encrypt(text)

  return {
    value: bufToB64(res.value),
    iv: bufToB64(res.iv),
  }
}
const divider = "::"
export function encryptBase64(text: BinaryLike): string {
  const res = encryptBase64Res(text)
  return `${res.value}${divider}${res.iv}`
}
export function decryptBase64(b64: string): Buffer {
  const [value, iv] = b64.split(divider)

  return decryptBase64Res({
    value,
    iv,
  })
}
export function decryptBase64Res(res: EncryptionResult<string>): Buffer {
  return decrypt({
    value: b64ToBuf(res.value),
    iv: b64ToBuf(res.iv),
  })
}
export function decrypt({ iv, value }: EncryptionResult<Buffer>): Buffer {
  const decipher = createDecipheriv(algorithm, secret, iv)
  return decipher.update(value)
}

Any attempt to migrate so far has just resulted in missing authentication tag errors, using the cryptography package in Python. Is it possible to work out the tag from this structure? There must be a tag being set by the initial encryption and being read by the decryption in the createCipheriv and createDecipheriv methods.

The NodeJS code misuses the GCM encryption by omitting the final() call, thus the tag is not determined and the authentication (the added value of the GCM encryption) is simply omitted. Some libraries support this by design (e.g. PyCryptodome is one, but to my knowledge not pyca/cryptography).
